# In python what does having = [] mean

Tags: python

I have some code and this is an extract of the code:

```
actualScoresTable = []
```

I was wondering what the `= []` bit means.

Comment: Python tutorial, [chapter 3, section 1.3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). LearnPython.org, *Learn The Basics*, [third page](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Lists). These are very basic syntax constructs that you can find in all Python tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign `empty list` to variable `actualScoresTable`.

Th type of `actualScoresTable` is `list`

try folowing:

```
>>> actualScoresTable = []
>>> print actualScoresTable
[]
>>> type(actualScoresTable)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

We can define list type variable in following way also:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> print a
[]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that an empty list is assigned to the variable name `actualScoresTable`.

Answer (score 1):

it is an empty list assigned to a variable actualScoresTable

if you want to add elements in the list you can use the built in function append()
like this

```
  actualScoresTable.append(the_element) #the_element could be string or int
```